# Can you help me find libraries, tutorials that can do video editing?

Tags: imovie

Now, I would like to know if you knew any tools, or tutorial, libraries, in Javascript or ASP NET C# or C# that allow to make a video editing

```
- creating a video from multiple images
- creation of an image composed of images, texts
- creating a video with scrolling text
- and as a bonus only transitional effects
```

I would like to avoid GIF formats that are not made for editing with higher quality (eg HD).

Thank you all!

Comment: try looking up ffmpg

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you know a significant amount of programming as making a video editor will require a lot of knowledge and effort. There aren't many tutorials covering how to specifically create a video editor. A library that many people use is [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/). There are tutorials on FFmpeg and you could always refer to the Documentation but I wouldn't rely entirely on a tutorial for your code. You are going to end up needing to build upon FFMPEG to make it suitable for what you are trying to do. You are also going to need to implement a graphics framework like OpenGL for rending as FFMpeg only handles audio and video and doesn't actually render it. Most of the other frameworks you are going to be using are graphical frameworks used for things like GUIs. Depending on what programming language you intend on developing it in, you can use the Qt framework, which has a version for just about every desktop programming language. Avoid using things like Windows forms with Visual Basic, since there are very few frameworks for Visual Basic that will be useful to you.

Comment: Any framework that can be used with .NET framework can be used with Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

I am researching the same topic.

Best open source C# wrapper of FFMpeg I have found so far is https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore
The documentation is quite light.

A "free for non-commercial use" product is https://ffmpeg.xabe.net/
If you can buy the commercial version, you would get support from the vendor